# How to include Amazon MWS client library in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2, amazon-mws

I'm an Amazon vendor and I've also a private e-commerce using Zend Framework 2.

How can I include MWS (Amazon Marketplace Web Service) API resource in ZF2 ?

Amazon give this script (for example) to manage order in Amazon account

https://developer.amazonservices.it/doc/orders/orders/v20130901/php.html

How can I include this script in ZF2?

Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWS [MWS client library](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/products/products/v20111001/php.html) for PHP seems have a quite old codebase; it doesn't utilizing an autoloader mechanism, non-namespaced classes with lot of double underscore prefixed method names everywhere. Aws also have a good [PHP sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/tree/master/src/Aws) but i'm not sure about MWS support.

Anyway, loading a non namespaced 3rd party libraries into a ZF2 application is quite possible via composer. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16385732/199593).

You may also want to take a look [Guzzle Aws](https://github.com/ddeboer/guzzle-aws) library for an alternative approach.