# How to load PHP library with no Namespaces in PHP ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, composer-php, hybridauth

Similar to the poster on [ZF2: autoloading libraries without namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366663/zf2-autoloading-libraries-without-namespaces), I need to load a non-namespaced library ***without* composer**.

Specifically, I need to load [HybridAuth](https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth) into Zend Framework 2.
I intend to use the submodule: https://github.com/heiglandreas/HybridAuth to interface with my application.

Do I need to create a classmap file?

Comment: How do you load other classes?

Comment: I don't use composer. So, I manually setup the namespace'd classes as one would normally do. However, this is the first time I've tried to setup a lib without namespaces and without using require/include. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "manually setup the namespace'd classes as one would normally do". (One would normally use a composer). What is your autoload code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the classmap strategy was the correct approach. Essentially, I needed to create the files that composer would have created on my own.

So, I register the namespaces to the directories *and* included the classmap.php file...

Using: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.loader.class-map-autoloader.html

```
Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader()
```

Taking advantage of the fact ZF2 looks for an autoload.php file in the vendor directory, I just placed all my code there...

Answer (score 0):

Load the library with require/require_once and use \ sign. This is the default namespace for PHP.

Comment: So... I need to perform a _require_once_ on all 50 or so files for that lib??

I thought this would be done by the _StandardAutoload_ class using classmaps. Am I wrong?

Comment: As long as I have a classmap file formatted with the correct directories, I can pass that to Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader() and it will perform the include() for me. :)